# Extracting Title, FirstName, MiddleName and LastName from Name field in Informatica

Tags: informatica

I have a table with a name field which consists of a Title (optional), FirstName, MiddleName (optional) and LastName. All records have a FirstName and LastName but not all records have either a Title or MiddleName. For example: 
Mr. Joey Tribbiani (no middlename) 
Rachel Karen Green (no title) 
Ms. Monica E Geller (all four fields) 
Phoebe Buffay (no title or middlename) and so on

The titles that I have on the table consists of either (Mr., Mrs., Ms., Ms, Sr., or Sra.)

In this scenario, how do I separate the Name field according to the Title, FirstName, MiddleName and LastName in Informatica?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using INSTR and SUBSTR functions in informatica

Say for example your input NAME is Mr.Joey Tribbiani

Note : I am assuming there is no space between Mr. and the firstname

**TITLE :**

IIF((INSTR(NAME,'.',1))=0,NULL,
(SUBSTR(NAME,1,INSTR(NAME,'.',1)-1)))

**FIRSTNAME :**

SUBSTR(NAME,INSTR(NAME,'.',1)+1,((INSTR(NAME,' ',1)-1)-INSTR(NAME,'.',1)))

SUBSTR('Mr.Joey Tribbiani',INSTR('Mr.Joey Tribbiani','.',1)+1,((INSTR('Mr.Joey Tribbiani',' ',1)-1)-INSTR('Mr.Joey Tribbiani','.',1)))

**LAST NAME :**

SUBSTR(NAME,INSTR(NAME,' ',1)+1)

SUBSTR('Mr.Joey Tribbiani',INSTR('Mr.Joey Tribbiani',' ',1)+1)

**Oracle SQL statements for your reference**

SELECT SUBSTR('Mr.Joey Tribbiani',1,INSTR('Mr.Joey Tribbiani','.',1)-1) FROM DUAL;

SELECT SUBSTR('Mr.Joey Tribbiani',INSTR('Mr.Joey Tribbiani','.',1)+1,((INSTR('Mr.Joey Tribbiani',' ',1)-1)-INSTR('Mr.Joey Tribbiani','.',1))) FROM DUAL;

SELECT SUBSTR('Mr.Joey Tribbiani',INSTR('Mr.Joey Tribbiani',' ',1)+1) FROM DUAL;

Please view the below links for detailed explanation on INSTR and SUBSTR

http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/instr.php
http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/substr.php

Regards,
Raj

Comment: Thanks for the reply Raj. The problem I'm having is in putting the extracted text within the proper columns. For example, when I run the query to extract the First character string in the fullname field I get either the titles (Mr. or Ms. and so on) or I get the First Name (Rachel or Phoebe). Then the MiddleName column then gets both the First Name and Middle Name string for those that have a title (for example: Monica E or Joey) .The LastName column comes out fine though. The presence of a title messes things up.

Comment: Hi,

The first condition
IIF((INSTR(NAME,'.',1))=0,NULL, (SUBSTR(NAME,1,INSTR(NAME,'.',1)-1)))  actually checks the existence of a '.' which actually presents when there is a title. As per condition if the existence of '.' is 0 then I am actually assigning the title to NULL (IIF((INSTR(NAME,'.',1))=0,NULL) else picking the title

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that there is a single space between every word.

What I did

1. Check if title exists and saved in a variable.
2. Find the number of spaces and checked if middle name existed or not.
3. Derived `title`, `first_name`, `middle_name` and `last_name` based on above conditions.

Create an expression transformation like this.

[image]

Here are the variable port conditions.

v_title_exists

```
IIF(
SUBSTR(upper(v_FULL_NAME),1,3)='MR.' OR
SUBSTR(upper(v_FULL_NAME),1,4)='MRS.' or
SUBSTR(upper(v_FULL_NAME),1,3)='MS.' or
SUBSTR(upper(v_FULL_NAME),1,2)='MS' or
SUBSTR(upper(v_FULL_NAME),1,3)='SR.' or
SUBSTR(upper(v_FULL_NAME),1,4)='SRA.'
,1,0)
```

v_number_of_spaces

```
length(v_FULL_NAME) - length(REPLACECHR(0,v_FULL_NAME,' ',''))
```

v_middle_name_exists

```
IIF(v_title_exists=1,
    IIF(v_number_of_spaces=3,1,0),
    IIF(v_number_of_spaces=2,1,0)
   )
```

v_title_exists

```
IIF(v_title_exists=1,
   substr(v_FULL_NAME,0,instr(v_FULL_NAME,' ',1,1) -1)
  , null
)
```

v_first_name

```
IIF(v_title_exists=1,
       substr(
           v_FULL_NAME,
            instr(v_FULL_NAME,' ',1,1)+1, 
             instr(v_FULL_NAME,' ',1,2)-instr(v_FULL_NAME,' ',1,1)
                      )
,
       substr(
           v_FULL_NAME,
            1, 
             instr(v_FULL_NAME,' ',1,1)-1
                      )
)
```

v_middle_name

```
IIF(v_middle_name_exists=1,
IIF(v_title_exists=1,
       substr(
           v_FULL_NAME,
            instr(v_FULL_NAME,' ',1,2)+1, 
             instr(v_FULL_NAME,' ',1,3)-instr(v_FULL_NAME,' ',1,2)
                      )
,
       substr(
           v_FULL_NAME,
            instr(v_FULL_NAME,' ',1,1)+1, 
             instr(v_FULL_NAME,' ',1,2)-instr(v_FULL_NAME,' ',1,1)
                      )
)
,
null)
```

v_last_name

```
IIF(v_middle_name_exists=1,
IIF(v_title_exists=1,
       substr(
           v_FULL_NAME,
            instr(v_FULL_NAME,' ',1,3), 
             length(v_FULL_NAME)
                      )
,
       substr(
           v_FULL_NAME,
            instr(v_FULL_NAME,' ',1,2), 
             length(v_FULL_NAME)
                      )
)
,
IIF(v_title_exists=1,
       substr(
           v_FULL_NAME,
            instr(v_FULL_NAME,' ',1,2), 
             length(v_FULL_NAME)
                      )
,
       substr(
           v_FULL_NAME,
            instr(v_FULL_NAME,' ',1,1), 
             length(v_FULL_NAME)
                      )
)
)
```

Comment: Hello Utsav, I tried the solution that you provided but I am getting NULL for the Title, FirstName and MiddleName columns while the LastName column shows a value of 0.

Comment: I ran the exact code and got expected output. Please use debugger tool and see what are you getting for each variable.